# Dynamic custom filter not working in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I have a codeigniter form with custom filter and datatables. I am using jquery, ajax to load data. What I expected is that When I choose company list for example, I want only selected company that load in a datatable. but what happen now is all the data load in datatables as if there's no filter. Please Help.

Thanks

This is my Controller

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Assetfilter extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('user');
        $this->load->model('assetfiltermdl');
        $this->load->model('worklistmdl');
        $this->load->helper('url'); 
        $this->load->helper('date');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->model('email_ctrl');
        $this->datauser = $this->session->userdata('logged_id');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('My_PHPMailer');
        //Do your magic here
    }

    //update 20 oct 2016 list kary.

    public function kary_reload()
    {
        $list = $this->assetfiltermdl->get_listkary();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $listkary) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = trim($listkary->idnik) . " ";
            $row[] = trim($listkary->kodenik). " ";
            $row[] =  rtrim($listkary->namakary). " ";
            $row[] = rtrim($listkary->namaper). " ";
            $row[] = trim($listkary->iddept). " ";
            $row[] = trim($listkary->jabatan). " ";
            $row[] = trim($listkary->flagstatus). " ";
            $row[] = trim($listkary->flagstatus). " ";


            /*$row[] = '<a href="<?php echo base_url(' . "'" . 'asset/karyawandetailform' . "'" .'); ?>/<?php echo $listkary[' . "'" . 'idnik' . "'" . '] ; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"> Detail</a>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(' . "'" . 'asset/karyawaneditform' . "'" . '); ?>/<?php echo $listkary[' . "'" . 'idnik' . "'" .'] ; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Detail</a>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(' . "'" . 'asset/karyawandeleform' . "'" . ');    ?>/<?php echo $listkary[' . "'" . 'idnik' . "'" .'] ; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="javascript:return confirm(' . "'" . 'Apakah Anda Sudah Yakin ?' . "'" . ')"  >Del</a>'; */

            $data[] =  ($row);
        }

        $output = array (
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->assetfiltermdl->count_all(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->assetfiltermdl->count_filtered(),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format

        $output = str_replace('\r'," ", $output );



        echo json_encode($output);
    }
 }
```

This is My model

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Assetfiltermdl extends CI_Model {

    var $kary_table = 'listkary';
    var $kary_column_order = array(null, 'update_date'); //set column field database for datatable orderable
    var $kary_column_search = array('idper','iddept','namakary','kodenik'); //set column field database for datatable searchable 
    var $kary_order = array('update_date' => 'desc'); // default order 

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

//update 20 oct 2016

  public function get_listkary()
    {
      $this->_get_listkary_query();
      echo $this->db->last_query();
      if($_POST['length'] != -1)
      $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();
    }

  private function _get_listkary_query()
    {

      //add custom filter here
      if($this->input->post('idper'))
      {
        $this->db->where('idper', $this->input->post('idper'));
      }
      if($this->input->post('iddept'))
      {
        $this->db->where('iddept', $this->input->post('iddept'));
      }
      //if($this->input->post('idsubdept'))
      //{
      //  $this->db->like('LastName', $this->input->post('LastName'));
      //}
      if($this->input->post('kodenik'))
      {
        $this->db->like('kodenik', $this->input->post('kodenik'));
      }
      if($this->input->post('namakry'))
      {
        $this->db->like('namakary', $this->input->post('namakry'));
      }

      $this->db->from($this->kary_table);

      $i = 0;

      foreach ($this->kary_column_search as $item) // loop column 
      {
        if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
        {

          if($i===0) // first loop
          {
            $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
            $this->db->where($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
          }
          else 
          {
            if($i===1) // second loop (iddept)
            {
                $this->db->where($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);  
            }   
          }

          if(count($this->kary_column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
            $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        }
        $i++;
      }

      if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->kary_column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->kary_order))
        {
            $order = $this->kary_order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }

    }


  private function _get_listkary_count()
    {

      //add custom filter here
      if($this->input->post('idper'))
      {
        $this->db->where('idper', $this->input->post('idper'));
      }
      if($this->input->post('iddept'))
      {
        $this->db->where('iddept', $this->input->post('iddept'));
      }
      //if($this->input->post('idsubdept'))
      //{
      //  $this->db->like('LastName', $this->input->post('LastName'));
      //}
      if($this->input->post('kodenik'))
      {
        $this->db->like('kodenik', $this->input->post('kodenik'));
      }
      if($this->input->post('namakry'))
      {
        $this->db->like('namakary', $this->input->post('namakry'));
      }

      $this->db->from($this->kary_table);

      $i = 0;

      foreach ($this->kary_column_search as $item) // loop column 
      {
        if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
        {

          if($i===0) // first loop
          {
            $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
            $this->db->where($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
          }
          else 
          {
            if($i===1) // second loop (iddept)
            {
              $this->db->where($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }
            else
            {
              $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);  
            } 
          }

          if(count($this->kary_column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
            $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        }
        $i++;
      } 

    }    

  public function count_all()
    {
        $this->_get_listkary_count();
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

  function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_listkary_count();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
}

/* End of file assetfiltermdl.php */
/* Location: ./application/models/assetfiltermdl.php */
```

and this is my view

```
<div class="right_col" role="main">
          <div class="">
            <div class="page-title">
              <div class="title_left">
                <h1> Data Karyawan </h1>
                    <h2> Informasi Data Karyawan </h2>
                    <p>
                        <a href ="<?php echo base_url('asset/karyawantambahform'); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Tambah Karyawan Baru</a>   
                    </p>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

          <div class = "row">

            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                  <h2>Daftar Karyawan</h2>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="x_content">

                <form id="form-filter" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="item form-group">
                        <label for="idper" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Perusahaan</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1" id="idper" name="idper">
                                <option>Pilih Perusahaan</option>
                                <?php foreach ($perushlov as $key => $value) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $value['idper']?>"><?php echo $value['namaper']?></option>}
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item form-group" >
                        <label for="iddept" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Departemen :</label> 
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1" id="iddept" name="iddept">
                                    <option >Pilih Departement</option>
                                    <?php foreach ($deptlov as $key => $value) { ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $value['iddept']?>"><?php echo $value['kodedept'] . ' - ' . $value['namadept'] . ' - ' . $value['namaper'] ?></option>}
                                    <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item form-group">
                        <label for="kodenik" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nama Karyawan</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="namakry">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item form-group">
                        <label for="kodenik" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Kode NIK</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kodenik">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item form-group">
                        <label for="LastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <button type="button" id="btn-filter" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
                            <button type="button" id="btn-reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </form>
                 <!-- <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered"> -->
                <table id="master_karyawan" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                 <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Kode Nik</th>
                        <th>Nama Karyawan</th>
                        <th>Perusahaan</th>
                        <th>Departemen</th>
                        <th>Jabatan</th>
                        <th>Aktif</th>
                        <th>Administrasi</th>
                    </tr>           
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var table;

$(document).ready(function() {

    //datatables
    table = $('#master_karyawan').DataTable({ 

        "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.       
        "order": [], //Initial no order.

        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo base_url('index.php/Assetfilter/kary_reload')?>",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": function ( data ) {
                data.perush = $('#idper').val();
                data.depart = $('#iddept').val();
                data.namakry = $('#namakry').val();
                data.kodenik = $('#kodenik').val();
            }
        },

        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [
        { 
            "targets": [ 0 ], //first column / numbering column
            "orderable": false, //set not orderable
        },
        ],

        //$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';

    });

    $('#btn-filter').click(function(){ //button filter event click
        table.ajax.reload(null,false);  //just reload table
    });
    $('#btn-reset').click(function(){ //button reset event click
        $('#form-filter')[0].reset();
        table.ajax.reload(null,false);  //just reload table
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is a virtually meaningless problem statement, especially when you show us server side and client side code and don't isolate anything specific. Take a few minutes to review [ask]

Comment: hi, thanks for your suggestion. I've edit my question. I hope you can understand my question and help me to solve my issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

maybe may answer to late but see this link hope can solved ur problems

http://mbahcoding.com/tutorial/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-server-side-datatables-custom-filter.html

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');

        $list = $this->assetfiltermdl->get_listkary();

        $opt = array('' => 'All List Karyawan');
        foreach ($karyawans as $karyawan) {
            $opt[$karyawan] = $karyawan;
        }

        $data['form_karyawan'] = form_dropdown('',$opt,'','id="karyawan" class="form-control"');
        $this->load->view('karyawan_view', $data);
    }
```

i hope this can explain ur code

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: if u think so its ok if delete my info cause i need a trigger for user if there any question to ask more further then im ready to explain so why i just show her link